# Is it legal to sell computers with Ubuntu installed

Tags: installation, legal, oem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I legally build and sell desktops with Ubuntu pre-installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93688/can-i-legally-build-and-sell-desktops-with-ubuntu-pre-installed)

Is it legal to assemble a computer, install ubuntu on it, and then sell the computer. I don't mean charging for the copy of ubuntu but for the price of parts and labor.

That being said, would it be legal to charge for a CD that has Ubuntu on it; not for the software itself but for the price of the CD used?