# resell ubuntu machines in the uk

Tags: 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I legally build and sell desktops with Ubuntu pre-installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93688/can-i-legally-build-and-sell-desktops-with-ubuntu-pre-installed)

Good morning,

I would be looking to sell ubuntu desktop machines in the uk.

Is this allowed, would i be able to set up a retail shop to do this?

I would be looking to partner with ebuyer and then installing the os
myself ready for the end user to use.

Kind regards
Simon Ball

Bedfordshire

Comment: Allowed by who? By UK authorities? We can't answer that, although I would be surprised if no. By Canonical? You better contact them directly, although I'm almost sure they would not mind (moreover, GPL licence would not allow them to forbid you to do what you want)