# Can I redistribute a custom Ubuntu-based distro for a profit?

Tags: custom-distributions, open-source

**I know that I can legally modify Ubuntu**, but is it legal to redistribute an operating system that's based on Ubuntu for a small profit? I want to know this before I get started on my Ubuntu-based Linux distro.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/93688/can-i-legally-build-and-sell-desktops-with-ubuntu-pre-installed

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate of that question. That question is about whether or not we can *sell physical computers* that contain *an actual Ubuntu OS.* This question is about whether or not we can *sell an Ubuntu derivative that we have created!* Those are *extraordinarily* different questions. This should be reopened.

Comment: I agree. That answer provided does not relate to this question. @EliahKagan As consolation for you here's a thread on Linux.com that has the information I think you're looking for. Let me know if you have other questions. http://archive09.linux.com/forums/topic/830

Comment: @japzone Eliah didn't create the question, it was asked by John (the real OP).

Comment: Whoops, typed in the wrong name. Oh well, doesn't matter now.

Answer (score 0):

Any redistribution of modified versions of Ubuntu must be approved, certified or provided by Canonical if you are going to associate it with the Trademarks. Otherwise you must remove and replace the Trademarks and will need to recompile the source code to create your own binaries. This does not affect your rights under any open source licence applicable to any of the components of Ubuntu. If you need us to approve, certify or provide modified versions for redistribution you will require a licence agreement from Canonical, for which you may be required to pay. For further information, please contact us (as set out below).