# Selling PC with Lubuntu, need clarification on legality

Tags: lubuntu, opera

I have a PC (**Dell Optiplex 170L**) I'm wishing to sell with **Lubuntu 16.04 LTS 32-bit**.

However, during install I enabled installation of 3rd party software & installed Opera web-browser after.
Am I legally allowed to sell this PC with Opera & the other 3rd party software from the OS installation?

Comment: I think you are, since it's just one sale. If you were planning on prepackaging a whole bunch of computers to sell with Ubuntu, it's a bit more complex. In any case, I'd read [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/93688/can-i-legally-build-and-sell-desktops-with-ubuntu-pre-installed) and maybe ask on a Legal site instead (you shouldn't take our advice, since we're not lawyers).

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to sell it at the same price you would sell it if you had installed absolutely nothing on it.  This means that the price should concern the PC only.  You are not allowed to sell or get any money for the software you have installed on it.  It's all free.

Comment: So, in the price range for a Refurbished PC of the same model?

Comment: Something like that, yes.