# Is it allowed selling a kvm virtual machine with Ubuntu? what about copyright?

Tags: 14.04, kvm-virtualization

I would like know if it is allowed creating a package with a KVM virtual machine + Ubuntu as OS and sell this package. Is there any restriction due to copyright or fees to pay?

I would not modify anything on the KVM or Ubuntu (just add java & firefox), just add my scripts on Ubuntu for the customers.
I saw that KVM's parts are licensed under various GNU licenses:

- KVM kernel module: GPL v2
- KVM user module: LGPL v2
- QEMU virtual CPU core library (libqemu.a) and QEMU PC system emulator: LGPL
- Linux user mode QEMU emulator: GPL
- BIOS files (bios.bin, vgabios.bin and vgabios-cirrus.bin): LGPL v2 or later

And ubuntu with GNU GPL.
Any idea?

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: I will not modify Ubuntu, just use it as it is and maybe add just java & firefox. I'm mostly worried for KVM virtual machine

Comment: So you're safe from the requirement to provide sources of your modifications, because you don't have any. Rest of the answer still applies.

Comment: this answer also gives good info and links https://askubuntu.com/a/142620/694267. regarding ubuntu.